# Wrong data saved / read from my datafiles in python

Tags: python, list

please look into the below code and result which i am getting

```
def load_watchers():
    try:
        users = {}
        with open('xyz.data','r') as user_file2:
            for line in user_file2:
                (user_id, movie_id) = line.split('\t')[0:2]
                users[movie_id] = user_id
        movie_genres_watchers = {}
        with open('abc.item','r') as movie_file2:
            for line in movie_file2:
                data = line.split('|')
                movie_id = data[0]
                movie_title = data[1]
                movie_genre = data[6:23]
                movie_genres_watchers.setdefault(movie_id, {})
                movie_genres_watchers[movie_id][movie_title] = movie_genre,users[movie_id]
        return movie_genres_watchers
    except IOError as ioerr2:
        print('File error in Function 2: ' + str(ioerr2))
```

And after executing the command,

```
movie_genres_watchers = load_watchers()
movie_genres_watchers['427']
```

I am getting a result as

```
{'To Kill a Mockingbird (1962)': (['0',
   '0',
   '0',
   '0',
   '0',
   '0',
   '0',
   '1',
   '0',
   '0',
   '0',
   '0',
   '0',
   '0',
   '0',
   '0',
   '0'],
  '912')}
```

which is partially correct.

Basically, in the result 912 is the used_id. And is not the only one. There are many user_id related to the movie for movie_id(427) which i got in output.

This movie_id is linked to many user_id. So ideally all those user_id should also come for this specific movie. But i am getting only one.

Can you guys please what wrong i am doing in the above code?
Appreciate if any one helps on this..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, could you provide an example of what is in both data files?  I am guessing this is related to every new user you read in xyz.data overwrites any previous data for that movie. You are going to want to have a way to append data to that particular movie. Also, a database maybe a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Next time please choose a proper title for your question. And no, you won't get answers faster if you claim your question is more important than everyone else's (which is what you just did)

Comment: [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 1):

When you create `users` you continually overwrite the value of `users[movie_id]`. You need to create `users` with a container like a list for its values.

```
try:
    users = {}
    with open('xyz.data','r') as user_file2:
        for line in user_file2:
            (user_id, movie_id) = line.split('\t')[0:2]
            users.setdefault(movie_id,[]).append(user_id)
    ...
```

or

```
import collections
,,,
try:
    users = collections.defaultdict(list)
    with open('xyz.data','r') as user_file2:
        for line in user_file2:
            (user_id, movie_id) = line.split('\t')[0:2]
            users[movie_id].append(user_id)
    ...
```